# Apache cxf webclient work with list of lists

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

That's the rest service, it sends a list of file lists:

```
@GET
@Path("duplicates")
@Secured
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<List<File>> getDuplicates(@QueryParam("distance") int distance)
```

Here is the client code, actually it can only work with a collection of files but how can i manage to get a list of file lists?

```
public Collection<? extends File> getDuplicates(String token, int distance) {
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(UserClientService.URL).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).path("duplicates").query("distance", distance).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);
    return client.getCollection(File.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
client.get(new GenericType<List<List<File>>>(){});
```